# Когда удаляется session bean?

Tags: java, java-ee

Cоздал сессионный бин и идея такова, что когда сессия истекает я вызываю метод `connectionClose();` чтоб закрыть соединение к базе.

в сервлете установил `httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);` но после этого времени бин не удаляется.
  
возможно sessionScope совсем не для этих целей используется или я делаю что-то не правильно?

```
 @SessionScoped
    public class MySqlConnection implements ConnectToDB {
        Connection connection;
        @PreDestroy
        private void connectionClose() throws SQLException {
                connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация была из пакета javax.faces.bean а надо было из javax.enterprise.context.